# Skype Web SDK - No package definition found for this config

Tags: lync, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I'm trying to use Skype's Web SDK and based on the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/websdk/docs/gettingstarted) I'm trying to initialize my application:

```
Skype.initialize({
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
}, function (api) {
    console.log('Initialized...');
    // Use the api
}, function (err) {
    console.log('Error initializing Skype Web SDK: ', err);
});
```

Every time I'm getting the following error from the Skype's bootstrapper:

> No package definition found for this config

Probably I'm missing configuration or something, but I don't know where to look. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API key is not unique per customer. It is not your Application/Object/Client ID. They are provided by Microsoft and can be found on the Web SDK's documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/websdk/docs/apiproductkeys